# Node form with fields loaded from another node or other entity

Tags: nodes, entities

I am stuck on this problem, I was making a 'field' to be available on many content types, but this field has itself many fields, so i decided making an entity to have those fields seperate. I choose an entity because i don't these information to be accessible in the searchs etc, and I don't need revisions. Now on the node form submission i would like to have both the fields of the node and the fields of the entity showing up on the same form, as if this entity was a field.  How can i do that ?

- If I use form_alter: ok i understood how to add widgets to the form, but then that means i have to re-write all the validation code etc from all fields ? Is it possible to load fields so that they will keep all their properties? (validation, submission etc)
- Would it be possible to create a field module that would load other fields from a node/entity type on each hook ?
- Any other solution ?

Idealy i would to find or make an 'entity-reference' module that does that job! (load field from one in the other when creating, editing, loading a node) !!

any help welcom, thanks !

dylan

Answer (score 1):

Isn't module [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) exactly what you are looking for? Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification, removal) of referenced entities.
>
> The primary use case is the parent -> children one (product display -> products, order -> line items, etc.), where the child entities are never managed outside the parent form.
>
> Existing entities can also be referenced.